How to label a polygon properly?
Consider following Metapost code:
vardef polygon_with_side(expr n, s) =
save a, b, r; numeric a, b, r;
a * n = 360; a + 2b = 180; r = s * sind(b) / sind(a);
for i = 0 upto n-1: (0, r) rotated (a * i) -- endfor cycle
enddef;

beginfig(1);
path p; p = polygon_with_side(21, 20);
draw p;
endfig;
bye;

This will generate a 21 sided polygon. How can I label these vertices properly? I know that we have Metapost labels but they give us only 8 directions.

Cross posted at the context mailing list. Please do not waste people's time.

You need to roll-your-own labels.   Here is one approach.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef polygon_with_side(expr n, s) =
save a, b, r; numeric a, b, r;
a * n = 360; a + 2b = 180; r = s * sind(b) / sind(a);
for i = 0 upto n-1: (0, r) rotated (a * i) -- endfor cycle
enddef;
beginfig(1);
path p; p = polygon_with_side(21, 20);
draw p;

pair m; numeric o, r;
m = origin; % median point of polygon
o = 10; % offset
r = abs(point 0 of p - m);  % radius

for i=1 upto 21:
  draw point i of p withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
  label(TEX("$p_{" & decimal i & "}$"), (1 + o / r)[m, point i of p]);
endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

If you need to stay with plain mpost then you must add "input TEX" to get the same function...
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.%{outputformat}";

vardef polygon_with_side(expr n, s) =
save a, b, r; numeric a, b, r;
a * n = 360; a + 2b = 180; r = s * sind(b) / sind(a);
for i = 0 upto n-1: (0, r) rotated (a * i) -- endfor cycle
enddef;


beginfig(1);
path p; p = polygon_with_side(21, 20);
draw p;

input TEX

pair m; numeric o, r;
m = origin; % median point of polygon
o = 10; % offset
r = abs(point 0 of p - m);  % radius

for i=1 upto 21:
  draw point i of p withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
  label(TEX("$p_{" & decimal i & "}$"), (1 + o / r)[m, point i of p]);
endfor

endfig;
end

Compile this with mpost.
If you are using context, then use the built-in textext() macro instead of TEX()
Alternative
If you are using context or you are happy to use the metafun format with luamplib, then you can use the freelabel or freedotlabel macros that are provided in that format.
These macros essentially automate what I have shown above.  The syntax is
freelabel(s, z, m);
freedotlabel(s, z, m);

where s is a <picture> or a <string>, z is the target <pair>, and m is the origin or median <pair>.  There is a freelabeloffset parameter to control the offset distance.
Note about the median
Since you have drawn your polygon at the origin, I was able to put m = origin; to get the median point.  But if your polygon is somewhere else, you should calculate the median point using something like this:
vardef median primary p = 
  origin for i=1 upto length p: + point i of p / length p endfor
enddef;

For even sided polygons this should be the same as center but not for those with an odd number of sides.

Thanks. How can I use textext in ConTeXt for this?

Just use textext(....) in place of TEX(....)
